# Trouble Clicking Buttons with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to press the find jobs button on the home page of indeed using selenium.  I have used By.id, By.xpath and By.className but it is still not working.  There are a lot of similar questions to the one I am asking but I already tried them and they aren't different from what I have already done.  I am using the Opera browser (don't want to use others) if that matters and the version is 3.4.0.

There is no error shown after execution.

Again the question is how do I click the button using selenium and java on an opera browser?

Appreciate the help.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class SeleniumLearning 
{
    WebDriver driverC;  
    WebDriver driverO;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    SeleniumLearning SL = new SeleniumLearning();
    //SL.invokeOperaBrowser();
    SL.indeedOpera();
    //SL.yahooOpera();
    //SL.duckduckgoOpera();
}
public void indeedOpera() throws InterruptedException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Selenium Stuff\\operadriver_win64\\operadriver.exe");
    driverO = new OperaDriver();
    //driverO.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driverO.manage().window().maximize();
    driverO.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driverO.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driverO.get("http://www.indeed.com");
    driverO.findElement(By.className("input_text")).sendKeys("HR");

    //Trying different methods
    //These don't work individually either
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driverO.findElement(By.id("fj")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driverO.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fj']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driverO.findElement(By.className("inwrapBorderTop")).click();
}
}
```

Comment: have you used javascript click? did you try to click on parent element or child element and see what happens ?

Comment: I have zero clue how to implement any of that.

Comment: And yet you are saying that you searched to forum for similar questions. please search again.

Comment: what is the error that you see?

Comment: For Kushal: There is no error it simply doesn't click the button.  It executes this driverO.findElement(By.className("input_text")).sendKeys("HR"); perfectly.  Then I think it executes it but website doesn't recognize it? (Not sure how selenium works behind the scenes.)

Comment: For Gaurang Shah: I am saying I don't have the knowledge to implement them. Also they don't talk about it this the first time I am reading about it.   I don't if this is the same for you but on the right you can see similar selenium questions and only one that has an answer recommends xpath which i am using.

Comment: `driverO.findElement(By.id("fj")).click();` worked for me using `chrome`. I'd make sure you have the latest `opera` driver and the latest `selenium` downloaded and try it again

Comment: I have opera 44.0 and selenium 3.4.0 both are the latest.  There is selenium 3.4.1 but it is only python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JS code to click the element as below:
driver.get("http://www.indeed.com");
    driver.findElement(By.className("input_text")).sendKeys("HR");

Thread.sleep(1000);

```
WebElement buttontoclick=driver.findElement(By.id("fj"));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", buttontoclick);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the site directly, I manually performed the test first.  I entered "hr" and then clicked the button.  At that time, the button was accessible via XPath //*[@id="fj"]

I then tried to go back a second time to see if the locator for the button only became enabled if there was search text, and I immediately noticed that the screen layout no longer looks the same.  I imagine if I cleared my cookies it would but I also noticed that upon second try, it already had my previous text in the textbox, but the locator for the button was not shown, only the division with XPath //*[@id="jobsearchform"]/div[5]/input

I don't know if this second locator will work with the first-time load of the web page or not, but it's likely it should work in either case.